# Query for logistic regression, multiple where exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

A logistic regression is a composed of a uniquely identifying number, followed by multiple binary variables (always 1 or 0) based on whether or not a person meets certain criteria.  Below I have a query that lists several of these binary conditions.  With only four such criteria the query takes a little longer to run than what I would think.  Is there a more efficient approach than below?  Note.  tblicd is a large table lookup table with text representations of 15k+ rows.  The query makes no real sense, just a proof of concept.  I have the proper indexes on my composite keys.

```
select  patient.patientid 
,case when exists
(
    select c.patientid from tblclaims as c
    inner join patient as p on p.patientid=c.patientid
    and c.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
    and c.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
    where patient.patientid = p.patientid
    group by c.patientid
    having count(*) > 1000
    )
    then '1' else '0'
    end as moreThan1000
,case when exists
(
    select c.patientid from tblclaims as c
    inner join patient as p on p.patientid=c.patientid
    and c.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
    and c.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
    where patient.patientid = p.patientid
    group by c.patientid
    having count(*) > 1500
    )
    then '1' else '0'
    end as moreThan1500
,case when exists
(
    select distinct picd.patientid from patienticd as picd
    inner join patient as p on p.patientid= picd.patientid
    and picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
    and picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
    inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
    where t.descrip like '%diabetes%' and patient.patientid = picd.patientid
    )
    then '1' else '0'
    end as diabetes
,case when exists
(
    select r.patientid, count(*) from patient as r
    where r.patientid = patient.patientid
    group by r.patientid
    having count(*) >1
    ) 
    then '1' else '0'
    end 


from patient
order by moreThan1000 desc
```

Comment: Have you tried LEFT JOINing to your condition queries rather than using the correlated subquery?

Comment: I have not.  I was thinking maybe I need to add full text catalog to my tblicd (the one with many rows of character data), but I'm not very familiar with that.  Could you provide an example of the `left join` you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by using subqueries in the from clause:

```
select q.patientid, moreThan1000, moreThan1500,
       (case when d.patientid is not null then 1 else 0 end),
       (case when pc.patientid is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from patient p left outer join
     (select c.patientid,
             (case when count(*) > 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as moreThan1000,
             (case when count(*) > 1500 then 1 else 0 end) as moreThan1500
      from tblclaims as c inner join
           patient as p
           on p.patientid=c.patientid and
              c.admissiondate = p.admissiondate and
              c.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
      group by c.patientid
     ) q
     on p.patientid = q.patientid left outer join
     (select distinct picd.patientid
      from patienticd as picd inner join
           patient as p
           on p.patientid= picd.patientid and
              picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate and
              picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate inner join
          tblicd as t
          on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
      where t.descrip like '%diabetes%'
     ) d
     on p.patientid = d.patientid left outer join
     (select r.patientid, count(*) as cnt
      from patient as r
      group by r.patientid
      having count(*) >1
     ) pc
     on p.patientid = pc.patientid
order by 2 desc
```

You can then probably simplify these subqueries more by combining them (for instance "p" and "pc" on the outer query can be combined into one).  However, without the correlated subqueries, SQL Server should find it easier to optimize the queries.

Comment: This didn't run for me on MSSQL 2008, I'm going to try to find out what's breaking it.

Comment: There is a typo on the query, it says `case when count(*) > 1o00 then 1 else 0 end)` and it should be `case when count(*) > 1000 then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: To make this run I have to remove the comma after `morethan1500` and add an alias after `(select r.patientid, count(*)` to get it to run. but it did run markedly faster.

Comment: this runs about 15x faster than it was :).  Going to have to study it a bit to get all of the meaning down.

Comment: You can also speed this up a bit further by combining queries (as I did with the "1000" and "1500" variables).  For now, though, think through how this is working, since it is a very typical way of bringing data together for analysis.

Comment: thanks for the insight.  i'm not a sql expert but i can see by joining on subqueries where the results are already pared down offers huge advantages over the way that i did it initially.

Answer (score 1):

Example of left joins as requested...

```
SELECT
    patientid,
    ISNULL(CondA.ConditionA,0) as IsConditionA,
    ISNULL(CondB.ConditionB,0) as IsConditionB,
    ....
FROM
    patient
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT patientid, 1 as ConditionA from ... where ... ) CondA
        ON patient.patientid = CondA.patientID
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT patientid, 1 as ConditionB from ... where ... ) CondB
        ON patient.patientid = CondB.patientID
```

If your Condition queries only return a maximum one row, you can simplify them down to

```
    (SELECT patientid, 1 as ConditionA from ... where ... ) CondA
```